# How to get the name of every title from accordion

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am developing a module for attendance of the employee. I am using accordion which will show the name of the year as their title. And in every accordion details I have put a grid which contains the name of the months. I can get the grid value in controller but can't get the name of the accordion header that's why I am not being able to show the desired result in grid. Can anyone please help me on this to get the heading of accordion title? My accordion details is given below :

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.attendence.Timeperiod' ,{
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        alias : 'widget.timeperiod',
        id: 'timeperiod',
        region: 'west',
        border: false,
        width: 150,
        height:400,
        split: true,
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            //bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
        },
        layout: {
            // layout-specific configs go here
            type: 'accordion',
            titleCollapse: true,
            animate: true,
            activeOnTop: true
        },

        initComponent: function() {

            var today = new Date();
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

            this.items = [{
                title: 'Year '+yyyy,
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-1),
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-2),
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-3),
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-4),
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            }];

            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

my months grid is given below :

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.attendence.Months' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.months',
    border: false,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    },
     store: 'Months',    
    hideHeaders: true,
    initComponent: function() {        
        this.store = 'Months';
        this.width = 150;      
        this.columns = [
        {
            dataIndex: 'months', 
            flex:1
        }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

my datagrid is given below :

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.attendence.Datagrid' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.datagrid',
    layout: 'fit',
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    },

    hideHeaders: false,
    initComponent: function() {  
        this.store = 'Attendences';
        //this.width = 400;      
        this.columns = [
        {
            text: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
            text: 'In-Time',
            dataIndex: 'intime'
        },
        {
            text: 'Out-Time',
            dataIndex: 'outtime'
        }


        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

my main window where all are added together is given below :

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.attendence.Attendencewindow' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.attendencewindow',
    title: 'Attendence Information',
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    autoShow: true,
    resizable: false,
    //maximizable: true,
    collapsible: true,
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            width: 550,
            bodyPadding: '8 0 8 0',
            border:false,
            layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
            },
            items:[{
            xtype: 'timeperiod'
            },{
            xtype: 'datagrid'
            }]
        }
        ];
        this.buttons = [

        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'New',
            iconCls: 'new',
            action : 'clear'

        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Save',
            iconCls: 'save',
            //iconAlign: 'top',
            action : 'save'


        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Print',
            iconCls: 'print',
            action: 'close'
            //scope: this

        }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

my controller is given below :

```
    Ext.define('Ext4Example.controller.Attendences', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: [
    'Attendences','Months'
    ],
    models: [
    'Attendence','Month'
    ],
    views: [
    'attendence.Timeperiod','attendence.Details','attendence.Attendencewindow','attendence.Editattendence','attendence.Months','attendence.Datagrid'
    ],

    refs: [{
        ref: 'stockaddForm',
        selector: 'form'
    }],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'datagrid': {
                itemdblclick: this.editUser
            },
            'months': {
                itemclick: this.show
            },
            'attendencewindow button[action=save]': {
                click: this.save
            }

        });
    },

    editUser: function(grid, record){
        var view = Ext.widget('editattendence');
        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    },
    show: function(grid, record) {
    var hi = grid.ownerCt.title;
        alert(hi);
        var a = Ext.getCmp('timeperiod');
        var store = this.getAttendencesStore();
        store.load({
            filters: [
              {property:'month', value:record.data.value},
              {property:'year', value:2012}
            ]          
        });

},

save: function(){
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();     //+1
        Ext.Msg.alert("Today is - ",dd+" - "+mm+" - "+yyyy);
}
});
```

Now can u tell me please how can i get the title of accordion like year 2012 or year 2011 I can get the months name by record.data.value but I can not take the title of accordion

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have registered yourself to the **[itemclick](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-itemclick)** event of the grid then will get the the grid itself as first argument within the callback. You now that the grid is directly nested within your accordion so you can simply refer to the **[ownerCt](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-property-ownerCt)**.

```
//lets pretend this is your callback
function(grid,record) {
    grid.ownerCt.title; // <- your accordion title
}
```

You should also take a look at `up()` ans `down()` which both required a component query selector. But in your case this seems the best way to do it.

**Edit**

here is the modified `timeperiod`

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.attendence.Timeperiod' ,{
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        alias : 'widget.timeperiod',
        id: 'timeperiod',
        region: 'west',
        border: false,
        width: 150,
        height:400,
        split: true,
        defaults: {
            // applied to each contained panel
            //bodyStyle: 'padding:15px'
        },
        layout: {
            // layout-specific configs go here
            type: 'accordion',
            titleCollapse: true,
            animate: true,
            activeOnTop: true
        },

        initComponent: function() {

            var today = new Date();
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

            this.items = [{
                title: 'Year '+yyyy,
                ident: 'accordion-panel',
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-1),
                ident: 'accordion-panel',
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-2),
                ident: 'accordion-panel',
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-3),
                ident: 'accordion-panel',
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            },{
                title: 'Year '+(yyyy-4),
                ident: 'accordion-panel',
                items: [{
                xtype: 'months'
                }]
                //html: 'Panel content!'
            }];

            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

And the modified Controller

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.controller.Attendences', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: [
    'Attendences','Months'
    ],
    models: [
    'Attendence','Month'
    ],
    views: [
    'attendence.Timeperiod','attendence.Details','attendence.Attendencewindow','attendence.Editattendence','attendence.Months','attendence.Datagrid'
    ],

    refs: [{
        ref: 'stockaddForm',
        selector: 'form'
    }],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'datagrid': {
                itemdblclick: this.editUser
            },
            'months': {
                itemclick: this.show
            },
            'attendencewindow button[action=save]': {
                click: this.save
            }

        });
    },

    editUser: function(grid, record){
        var view = Ext.widget('editattendence');
        view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    },
    show: function(grid, record) {
    var hi = grid.up('[ident=accordion-panel]');
        alert(hi.title);
        var a = Ext.getCmp('timeperiod');
        var store = this.getAttendencesStore();
        store.load({
            filters: [
              {property:'month', value:record.data.value},
              {property:'year', value:2012}
            ]          
        });

    },

    save: function(){
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();     //+1
            Ext.Msg.alert("Today is - ",dd+" - "+mm+" - "+yyyy);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi sra, thanks a lot for your reply. I have edited my post for complete view. I want to get the accordion title in controller where year: 2012 which is now static . Please can you help on this

Comment: @SumonBappi Edit done. I added a private property to which you can now refer when navigating upward using `up()` (done in the controller). This should show you the title.

Comment: @SumonBappi Your'e welcome :) So you may consider checking my answer as correct :) ?

Comment: yes for that functionality absolutely. But now I need to set selected the current month in accordion panel which's value is shown by the grid. Can you please help me on this ?!

Comment: This is my first post on here. Now what should I do and how can you please tell me ?